# Error in getting Table from VBA recordset

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am using a mySql server connection to get table data into excel.  I have a total of three queries, two of which work perfectly and are copied correctly from copyFromRecordSet.  However, the third query does not work correctly when I use copyFromRecordset.  It gets two of the columns I want, but leaves off the next five.  The query works correctly when I use it in a database GUI so that is not the issue.

I am trying to use an alternative to copyFromRecordSet, a piece of code which I altered from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/246335/how-to-transfer-data-from-an-ado-recordset-to-excel-with-automation.

```
'Open and copy the recordset to an array to allow for copying into worksheet
RS.Open PriceChangeQuery
recArray = RS.GetRows

recCount = UBound(recArray, 2) + 1 '+1 since the array is zero-based
fldCount = RS.Fields.Count

' Check the array for contents that are not valid when
    ' copying the array to an Excel worksheet
    For iCol = 0 To fldCount - 1
        For iRow = 0 To recCount - 1
            ' Take care of Date fields
            If IsDate(recArray(iCol, iRow)) Then
                recArray(iCol, iRow) = Format(recArray(iCol, iRow))
            ' Take care of OLE object fields or array fields
            ElseIf IsArray(recArray(iCol, iRow)) Then
                recArray(iCol, iRow) = "Array Field"
            End If
        Next iRow 'next record
    Next iCol 'next field

'Transpose and copy the array to the worksheet,
'starting in cell A2
CompareFile.Sheets("VendorFilteredPriceChangeReport").Cells(2, 1).Resize(recCount, fldCount).Value = TransposeDim(recArray)
'CompareFile.Sheets("VendorFilteredPriceChangeReport").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS

'Close ADO objects
RS.Close
```

And this is the TransposeDim function.

---

```
Function TransposeDim(v As Variant) As Variant
' Custom Function to Transpose a 0-based array (v)

Dim X As Long, Y As Long, Xupper As Long, Yupper As Long
Dim tempArray As Variant

Xupper = UBound(v, 2)
Yupper = UBound(v, 1)

ReDim tempArray(Xupper, Yupper)
For X = 0 To Xupper
    For Y = 0 To Yupper
        tempArray(X, Y) = v(Y, X)
    Next Y
Next X

TransposeDim = tempArray
End Function
```

However, when I run this piece of code the query is again leaving off the last five columns.

Any insights as to how to fix this piece of code or insights as to why copyFromRecordSet would be behaving strangely would be appreciated

Comment: First of all, instead of having to call TransposeDim, why not store the items in the array correctly in the loop? Just change ```recArray(iCol, iRow) = Format(recArray(iCol, iRow))``` to ```recArray(iRow, iCol) = Format(recArray(iRow, iCol))```, and any other references.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll do that

Comment: Turns out I didn't have fldCount set to a value--the piece of code works now, just getting the same bug as copyFromRecordset

Answer (score 0):

In order to access some records properly, a recordSet's cursor must be set to client side.  I was able to do this by using: 
`RS.CursorLocation = adUseClient` in my code, right after opening the recordset using my query.  I was then able to copy the data from the recordset using only `CompareFile.Sheets("VendorFilteredPriceChangeReport").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS` and I got the correct data in my workbook.